# How to remove all files in a directory except hidden ones?

Tags: bash, rm

I'm cleaning an output directory before I put things in it.  I want to track the output directory in git with a `.gitkeep` file, but this keeps on getting deleted with my `rm -rf "$OUT_DIR"` line in a bash script.

Is there a way to remove the contents of a directory but keep either hidden files or somehow just keep that `.gitkeep` file?

Answer (score 9):

By default `bash` doesn't glob dot-files, so to remove everything but hidden files in `bash`, using `rm`:

```
rm *
```

Sample output:

```bsh
~/tmp$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 giu 11 20:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 user user 4096 giu 11 08:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:00 .1
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:00 2
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:00 3
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:00 4
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:00 5
~/test$ rm *
~/tmp$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 giu 11 20:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 user user 4096 giu 11 08:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:00 .1
```

To remove everything but `.gitkeep` in `bash`, enabling globbing for dot-files and using `rm`:

```
shopt -s dotglob
rm !(.gitkeep)
```

Sample output:

```bsh
~/tmp$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 giu 11 20:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 user user 4096 giu 11 08:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:19 1
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:19 2
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:19 3
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:19 4
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:19 5
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:19 .gitkeep
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:19 .hidden
~/tmp$ shopt -s dotglob
~/tmp$ rm !(.gitkeep)
rm: cannot remove ‘.’: Is a directory
rm: cannot remove ‘..’: Is a directory
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 giu 11 20:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 user user 4096 giu 11 08:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 giu 11 20:19 .gitkeep
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that a recursive remove `rm -r *` behaves differently to an non-recursive `rm *` with respect to hidden files.  The first removes them but the second does not (with default shell options).  But, of course, recursive is needed in order to remove subdirectories.

My solution is to use move which does leave hidden files in place, instead of remove.  It is a couple more lines but makes sense when you do it (no odd options to remember).

```
mkdir ../deleteme
mv * ../deleteme
rm -rf ../deleteme
```

Comment: Works exactly as I want

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
shopt -u dotglob        # disable globbing for dot files
ls *
```

If everything looks okay, replace `ls` by `rm`.

Comment: You probably want `ls -d *` to avoid listing contents of any matching directory.

Answer (score 0):

`rm *` works fine if your directory doesn't contain subdirectories (see [the answer of @kos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209067/30497)). However, if you need a recursive solution that also removes all subdirectories, then (as @meesern [has pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374391/30497)) `rm -r *` is not what you want, since it *does* remove hidden files and subdirectories.

Instead, you can use `find` to list and delete non-hidden files and subdirectories (adapted from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/318211/31948)):

```
find YOUR_DIRECTORY -not -path '*/\.*' -delete
```

This will delete all non-hidden files in `YOUR_DIRECTORY` and all subdirectories that are empty after the non-hidden files have been removed.

It will *not* remove content inside a hidden directory (e.g. `YOUR_DIRECTORY/.foo/bar/baz`). As a result, you might get some warnings like

```
find: cannot delete 'some/directory/here': Directory not empty
```

But you can safely ignore them.